# Content displayed over the safe area iOS Capcitor angular

Tags: ios, angular, capacitor

[image]

I am using capacitor for building this iOS app but the content displayed over safe area. I have used many css in app-header or body tag. But none of them are working. I also installed a plugin named **capacitor-plugin-safe-area** but can understand what to do after reading their documentation.

I am using angular 11 for front end and .net core for back end api.

Comment: did you get this figured out? running into the same problems myself.

Comment: capacitor can not be configured for IOS header . I did it from xcode settings while publishing

Comment: actually the below answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make changes to capacitor.config file :

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
appId: 'com.company.appname',
appName: 'My Capacitor App',
webDir: 'www',
ios: {
     contentInset: 'always',
     },

 };

export default config;
```

Add contentInset property as 'always' for ios devices.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this solution does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `safe-area-inset-*`

```
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
```

Keep in mind that Capacitor has a plugin for more status bar options like light/dark mode.

Comment: This worked for me but I needed to add this to my viewport: `viewport-fit=cover`