# Status bar covers part of the application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have a problem that the status bar covers part of the application, and I would like the status bar to be separate from the application. I use Angular 12 and Capacitor V4, should i use capacitor save-area package? This issue only appear on iphone with notch, on Android, iPad works very well.
This is what the app looks like when you run it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlBB3.png)
When I minimize the apps and come back again, the app gets a black bar at the top that just separates the apps and I wish it was like this all the time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y05Iw.jpg)

Aplication with black bar on top.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897759/content-displayed-over-the-safe-area-ios-capcitor-angular) can help or you may try with [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-plugin-safe-area?activeTab=readme)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.